# Finding subset List of Python List based on an input integer

Tags: python-3.x, list

I want a subset list from input List based on input integer value.

For Example:

```
Input List: [3,7,9,11,12]
Input Value: 2
Output List: [1,7,9,11,12]
# 2 is subtracted from first element of list

Input List: [3,7,9,11,12]
Input Value: 5
Output List: [5,9,11,12]
#5 is subtracted from list in sequence manner, first 3 is subtracted then remaining 2 is subtracted from 7 hence output is [5,9,11,12]
```

Comment: Where is the code you used to try and accomplish this?

Comment: m = 2
sum = 0
for i in range(len(temp)):
    sum = sum + temp[i]
    if temp[0] == m: 
        del temp[0]
        break
    elif m < temp[i]:
        temp[i] = temp[i] - m
        break
    elif m == sum:
        temp = temp[i:]
        break

Comment: Please explain your second example.

Comment: Please check I have updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `numpy.cumsum()` if modules are allowed:

```
import numpy as np
input_list = np.asarray([3, 7, 9, 11, 12])
input_integer = 5
output_list = input_list[input_list.cumsum() > input_integer]
output_list[0] -= input_integer - input_list[input_list.cumsum() <= input_integer].sum()
print(output_list)
```

**Output:**

```
[ 5  9 11 12]
```

What i did there:

Since total sum is to be subtracted from starting, using cumulated sum will tell you where to crop the list from.

Then set the first element = first elem - (input_integer - cropped list's sum)

Comment: Thank you very Much TJCWorld. It would be great if it could have done without modules.

Answer (score 2):

Recursive solution:

```
def subfrom( lst, n ):
    if n<=0 or lst == []:
        # No change necessary
        return lst
    if lst[0] <= n:
        # First element gets removed
        # Return the list you get by removing the leftover from the rest of the list
        return subfrom( lst[1:], n-lst[0] )
    # Reducde first element
    return [lst[0]-n] + lst[1:]
```

Comment: Great Scott, Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```
# First set of test variables
list1 = [3,7,9,11,12]
input1 = 2

# Second set of test variables
list2 = [3,7,9,11,12]
input2 = 5

def eval_list(input_value, iterable, output = None):
    if output is None:
        output = []

    for i, v in enumerate(iterable):
        current = iterable[i]
        if input_value > 0:
            if v <= input_value:
                input_value -= current
            else:
                current -= input_value
                input_value = 0
                output.append(current)
        else:
            output.append(current)

    return output
```

Run for each data set and output results:

```
res1 = eval_list(input1, list1)
res2 = eval_list(input2, list2)

print(f"Set 1: {res1}")
print(f"Set 2: {res2}")
```

Output:

```
Set 1: [1, 7, 9, 11, 12]
Set 2: [5, 9, 11, 12]
```